# Что означает dummy package в Linux репозитории?

Tags: linux, repository, kali-linux

При установке OpenBazaar выдало что не хватает libgconf2-4.

```
sudo apt search libgconf2-4
```

И в описании дано такое : `GNOME configuration database system (dummy package)`

Comment: доп. описание - https://serverfault.com/a/610040/477854

Comment: что за linux, debian, ubuntu?

Comment: Linux дистр - kali

Comment: возможно в данном случае это указание на то, что пакет является частью `gconf`

Comment: Т.е если используется не gnome, то могут быть проблемы ?

Answer (score 2):

Как вам уже сказали, Dummy-пакеты используются для того, чтобы "обмануть" систему. Никакой опасности в них нет. Например, в вашей ситуации dummy-пакет `libgconf-2-4` будет установлен вместе с реальным пакетом `libgconf2-4`. Обратите внимание на лишнюю чёрточку в имени. Именно для того пакет и нужен, чтобы создать синоним для случаев, когда программа ищет нужный пакет по ошибочному имени. Он просто создаст симлинк на реальный пакет с таким же именем, так что можете не волноваться. Единственная проблема, которая тут может возникнуть - это если реальный пакет будет удалён, а dummy останется и будет ссылаться в пустоту. Но такого на практике почти не бывает, так как эти пакеты обычно зависимы и удаляются вместе.

Answer (score 0):

> Well, one use is to fool your system into thinking that a dependancy
>   is satisfied when in reality it is not...
>
> Ну, одно использование - чтобы обмануть вашу систему, думая, что зависимость
>   удовлетворена, когда на самом деле это не так ...

[Источник](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-is-a-dummy-package-630069/)

Comment: А есть ли какая либо опасность использования dummy пакетов ?